# c# standard output readtoEnd()

Tags: c#, .net, process, console-application

I have the following problem. I run an exe but i can't see in my console application everything that the exe contains. I've expected to see in the console application at least the text i am writing in the running executable. where am i wrong?

1) how can i print in the console application the text that i'm writing in the exe that i run? is that possible? i would also like to use tje standard input stream. I mean I would like to read from the exe and also write in the exe using my application.Here is the code:

Need some help. Thx!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s;



        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.FileName = @"notepad.exe";

        using (Process pp = Process.Start (p))
        {
            string output = pp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            //pp.WaitForExit();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = pp.StandardError;

            // finally output the string
            Console.WriteLine("output is: "+output+"....."+myStreamReader.ReadLine());
          //  pp.Close();
            Thread.Sleep (2000);
        }
```

Comment: do you expect to dump in the console the text you wrote in notepad ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you're trying to do, exactly.  Why do you need a separate process?

Comment: I am not sure Notepad.exe writes to the standard output or standard error...  it is not a command-line program, it is a GUI program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Standard*` streams are only applicable to console applications. You are running notepad, which is not a console application.

Comment: i accepted your answer. I would like to ask you how can i acces the menu from the running exe using an application?

Comment: @elisa: As I already told you the last time, please post new questions as new questions and not in the comments of old ones. You will get a wider audience and better answers this way. Besides: Your questions so far confuse me: What exactly are you trying to achieve in the big picture?

Comment: i have a running executable (lets say a form application that contains a list of mail addresses) I run the exe file from my c# application using process.start(). everything is great till now. but how can i programatically link the second mail address from the running executable (usinf my application from where i run the exe) and send a message to the opened window? plz help:)..i did search a lot..ask a lot..but no..conclusion:)

Comment: @elisa: I was asking about the big picture. Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve? Do you have control over the second exe, i.e. is it developed by you?

Comment: because i have an exe file on which this is how i have to work. no i don't have the source cod. i just have the exe file. i don't know how to set the control to the second form , how to actually go programatically to the second mail address (from the list) from the exe i run using process.start in order to click it and post a message (programatically).

Comment: @elisa: You are trying to control another program. This isn't trivial. It is possible, sure, but not trivial. I am still not convinced, that this is the way to go. Most likely, there is a better way, i.e. to access the data the program shows directly or similar.

Comment: do you have some better ideas? the thig is that the only thing i have is the exe file:)

Comment: @elisa: I have no better ideas, because I don't know the exe you are using and I don't know the reason, why you want to control that exe. I know nothing about your use case, so I can't have a better idea.

Comment: @elisa: Maybe you can tell me which exe it is (if it is a program that is available on the internet)...

Comment: i just know that wen it runs it pops up a window with mail addresses.

Comment: @elisa: I am sorry, but you are really of no help, identifying your problem, so I will stop now. Good luck.